# Remove fixed filename extension in one-liner

Tags: regex, ruby

When I do

```
ruby -e 'print "file: #{ARGF.filename}"' test1.adoc
```

it prints `test1.adoc`, but what I am looking for is to have the extension removed, so I just get `test1`. If do

```
$ touch test1.adoc
$ ruby -e 'print "file: #{ARGF.filename}.sub('.adoc','')"' test1.adoc
Traceback (most recent call last):
    1: from -e:1:in `<main>'
-e:1:in `filename': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - test1.adoc (Errno::ENOENT)
```

Using `pop` is temping to get a generic solution, but that seams harder going down that path...

## Question

Can anyone figure out howto remove `.adoc` in my one-liner?

Comment: What if it's `/foo/bar/test.adoc`? What would you like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```rb
ruby -e 'print "file: #{File.basename(ARGF.filename, '"'.*'"')}"' test.adoc
```

The [`File.basename`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/File.html#method-c-basename) with the second argument set to `.*` returns file name without any extensions, but you need to quote the single quotes correctly in order to keep syntax right.

In `'"'.*'"'`, the first `'` closes the currently open `'` before `print`, then `"'.*'"` adds `'.*'` to the line of code, then `'` re-starts the code line to be closed with the trailing `'`.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`File.basename`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/File.html#method-c-basename) to remove the extension, and the rest of the file path.

```
puts File.basename('test1.adoc', '.*')  # test1
puts File.basename('/foo/bar/test1.adoc', '.*')  # test1
```